# Laurent Series Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

[image]

Basically for this question, I only know 
[image]

But I do not quite understand what I have to do with different domains 
Any useful advice is welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with $1<|z|$, then $\left|\dfrac{1}{z}\right|<1$, so
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{z-1}{z(1+z^{2})}&=\dfrac{1-\dfrac{1}{z}}{1+z^{2}}\\
&=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{z^{2}}-\dfrac{1}{z^{3}}}{1+\dfrac{1}{z^{2}}}\\
&=\left(\dfrac{1}{z^{2}}-\dfrac{1}{z^{3}}\right)\left(1-\left(\dfrac{1}{z^{2}}\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{z^{2}}\right)^{2}-\cdots\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! I just have to make sure that the series convergent, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.